# Assign and return a variable in one run

Tags: javascript

Are these structs the same without side effects?

```
// First variant
var a;
var assignVar = function(){ return a = 10; }
var b = assignVar()

// Second variant
var a;
var assignVar = function(){ a = 10; return a; }
var b = assignVar()
```

Can I assign a value to a variable and return it at the same time? Or should I first assign it, then return? Are there any caveats and different behaviour?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the same, assignment returns the value etc.

Comment: that isn't very maintainable/readable.

Comment: Of course, returning from an IIFE to nothing, makes no sense.

Comment: He is just doing it to illustrate the point. otherwise someone would probably say the function never executed.

Comment: @synthet1c - I realize that, just saying that `var b = (function() { return a; }());` would make more sense, as it's actually returned somewhere.

Comment: Just updated the code to make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is safe and both functions are equivalent. The assignment operator of nearly all languages is strictly defined to return the assigned value, the only exception I am aware of is in languages like C++ where you can overload the operator. In Javascript assignment always 'returns' the assigned value.

The relevant authority is the [ECMAScript 2015 specification section 12.14.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators), in which all control paths exit with *"Return rval"*, which is the part to the right of the operator.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do the first way. I would wrap it in parens though so you and others know your are doing something to the variable, and you will look twice.

```
(function(){ return (a = 10) })()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would better do it like this

```
var a = (function(){ return 10; }())
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation. It's unclear why your answer is "better" than the OP's implementation -- and you don't really answer the original questions.

Comment: I just provided a third alternative that I preferred instead of those provided in the question (before the edit). In such a trivial case there is no significant difference, it is only cleaner and perhaps faster  .